# How to build:production a new app.js and host the project on firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I just created a node js project with just one api endpoint in the app.js. I want to host project on Firebase so that I can call the api that returns just a message string.

I have the project setup in firebase. Locally I did "firebase init hosting" and "firebase deploy". When I visit the firebase genareted url I can only see "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete". In Angular project I know that one have to do "build:production" that will generate the /dist files before before doing "firebase deploy.

Please how to one build production in a just Node js app before deploying to firebase?.

[image]